# Integrating an equation of motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws

My physics book says that the equation of motion $ 2 \dot{r} \dot{\varphi} + r \ddot{\varphi} = 0 $ can be integrated once to give the equation $ mr^2 \dot{\varphi}= \text{const} $, assuming constant mass $m$. The solution is certainly correct, since differentiation returns the original equation. But how do I integrate this equation of motion? I have tried product integration and separation of variables, but did not get anywhere. My CAS does not want to give me an answer, either. Probably the problem has an easy answer, but at the moment I fail to see it.

Comment: You want to integrate the original one to obtain the simplified version or you want to integrate $mr^2 \dot{\phi}= L$???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form of the E.o.M almost implies straight away there's a conserved quantity: i.e. it looks as if you can write it of the form $\frac{d}{dt}(...) = 0$. In the case you presented, $2 \dot{r} \dot{\phi} + r \ddot{\phi} = 0$, it should be easy to see that this can be written as
$$ \frac{1}{r} \frac{d}{dt} \big(r^2 \dot{\phi} \big) =0 \ ,$$
which is exactly the form we're looking for. It implies that $r^2 \dot{\phi}$ is a constant and conserved. We introduce the constant $m$ just as we would when doing indefinite integrals, as this doesn't affect the equations of motion. This is how we conclude that $m r^2 \dot{\phi}=const$. There's also less 'guess work' if you know to look for something of the form $\frac{d}{dt}(...) = 0$ in the E.o.M, rather than starting from the solution and just checking it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Well, it seems that guessing is the only way to proceed in this case. The fact that both Mathematica and Maxima don't give a result when trying to integrate the E.o.M. already suggests, that an algorithmic solution, which I was looking for, is either not available or rather difficult, isn't it?

Comment: Ah no, as the other answer says we're not strictly doing any integration at all. Rather we're writing the EoM in the form I've written above, i.e. the time derivative of another term. Another point, the reason your solver can't to the integral is because of this $\frac{1}{r}$ term in my answer. Note that if you multiplied the through by $r$ in the EoM (which we're assuming $\neq 0$) you can actually do the integral and you'll get the correct answer (have a try!).

Comment: You are right, Mathematica can integrate the lhs of the EoM multiplied by r. Maxima has the advantage of being able to nicely integrate an equation alltogether, but in this case fails even with the lhs multiplied by r.

Answer (score 1):

I remember finding this confusing.  Sometimes they call conserved quantities 'integrals of the motion', which I really don't think is a good name.

Let us differentiate
$$
mr^2\dot\phi \to \frac{d}{dt}mr^2\dot\phi=2mr\dot r\dot \phi+m r^2\ddot \phi=mr(2\dot r\dot \phi+r \ddot \phi)
$$

Its called an integral of the equation of motion because if you differentiate it you get something proportional to the EOM.

It may seem hard to try and guess what proportionality factor you have to have in order to integrate it and get a constant, however when you get to lagrangians there are nice techniques to find conserved quantities.